# which of the following is not a possible value of $(e^{f})^{''}(0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function on closed unit disk,  $\{z \in \mathbb{C}| |z|\leq 1\}$. Assume that $ |f(z)|\leq 1$ for all complex numbers in the closed unit disk.

Then which of the following is not a possible value of $(e^{f})^{''}(0)$?

(a)$ 2$
( b) $6$
( c) $\frac{7}{9}e^{1/9}$
( d)$\sqrt(2) + i\sqrt(2)$

I don't know how to solve this problem. I would like to have some hint so that I can solve the problem on my own.

Comment: *Using maximum modules principle, we can conclude the function is constant inside the disk and takes maximum value on the boundary.* Uhm... I can think of a few $f$-s that are *not* constant ("inside").

Comment: Sorry I have edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g=e^f$, then

$g''(0)= \frac{2}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{g(z)}{z^3} dz$.

Since $|\frac{g(z)}{z^3}| \le e$ for $|z|=1$, we get

$|g''(0)| \le \frac{2}{2 \pi } \cdot e \cdot 2 \pi=2e$.

Now $6 > 2 e.........$

Answer (score 3):

You're given $|f(z)|\le 1$ without any information about $f'(z)$ and $f''(z)$, so this leads naturally to Cauchy's integral formula, since $(e^f)''(a)=\frac{2!}{2\pi i}\int_c \frac{e^{f(z)}}{(z-a)^3}dz$ gives you information about the derivatives using only information about $f$.  Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

Using test functions like $f(z)=az^2$ with $|a|\le 1$, you can show that several of the numbers *are* possible values of $(e^f)''(0)$. The remaining value can be excluded if you believe the problem setter did their job correctly. Or maybe using a variant of Schwarz' lemma?